# Is it somehow possible to use doxygen to genererate CMake documentation?

Tags: cmake, doxygen

I would like to use `doxygen` to generate documentation for `.cmake` files. I already added `*.cmake \` to the `Doxyfile` ( Configuration for doxygen ) `FILE_PATTERNS` section, but it seems that doxygen cannot handle `.cmake` files.

**test.cmake**

```
#[==[
@ingroup module-impl
@brief Output a node in the graph

Queries the properties for modules and generates the node for it in the graph
and its outgoing dependency edges.
#]==]
function (_anyfunction var module)
endfunction()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> use doxygen to genererate CMake documentation?

You know what has to be done. Download [Doxygen source](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/) and implement the support for CMake syntax and parsing comments in CMake, just like it is implemented [for other languages](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/src/pycode.l#L169). See https://www.doxygen.nl/support.html .

There is no support for CMake at this time.

> Is it somehow possible

Write basically a small compiler/parser, that takes CMake source code and transforms it to short C or Python or other programming language source code and then run Doxygen via generated files.

With the format presented, that would be a short script that searches for `fuction(...` lines, extracts the function name, extracts the comment before it, and generates `// @brief`-ish comments like comments followed by `void _anyFunction();`.

---

You could also do like:

```
FILE_PATTERNS = *.cmake
EXTENSION_MAPPING = cmake=C  # or Python or other
```

And then try to squeeze other programming language into CMake files:

```
#[=[*/
/// @function _anyFunction
/// @brief Output a node in the graph
///
/// Queries the properties for modules and generates the node for it in the graph
void _anyFunction();
#/*]=]
function (_anyfunction var module)
endfunction()
```